# VB.NET ServerManager.Sites Default Web Site

Tags: vb.net, iis

I am updating an existing MSI and I am stucked on a line of code that worked before but seems to be no longer working.

I want to get the Default Web Site but when I try with the code below, it returns me nothing. Is there a better way to find the root website?

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.Administration

Using serverMngr As ServerManager = New ServerManager
    'Obtenir le site par défaut
     Dim leSite As Site = serverMngr.Sites("Default Web Site")
End Using
```

In the IIS panel, I can see "Default Web Site".

Answer (score 0):

I've made a for loop to display all the websites and looking for the website with id 1 and it showed that WebSite1 was my default web site.

I tried to uninstall IIS Express 10 that was installed on my computer and it worked after that.